# silicone caulking at uneven tight tile joints / gap

Tags: tile, caulking

We have uneven joints around the tub and shower wall. How can we best caulk silicone? Is there any tricks or recommended tools? We are worried about the tight spots.

Comment: It is unclear what "uneven joints around the tub and shower wall" is supposed to mean. More  info is needed. Photos would be best. If we know what the "right spots" are we may be able to help.

Comment: Definitely photos that show what you are trying to describe and you must remove any existing silicone applications to apply new silicone, or caulking of any kind. This is a bit of a job but with photos, I’ll tell you the best fix.

Answer (score 1):

not entirely sure what your concern is, but one tip I would suggest is you can carefully mask areas with painters tape where you don't want caulk so that you can spread caulk more effectively (thouroughly) in the uneven joints.